# PostgreSQL migration and restore

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

I have a PostgreSQL v7.3 installation that I need to migrate with a minimum of fuss to a newer, resource-rich and much faster machine that already has PostgreSQL 9.1.13 installed. I have the source code to the version of v7.3 that I was using, which, if compiled and installed (easy enough) would make it dead-simple (assuming prying 9.1.13 out of there first isn't a problem), but I'd prefer to use the newer version if possible.

I have the v7.3 pgsql directory on the new machine as a copy from the older machine, not presently associated with the PostgreSQL on this one.

There are a *lot* of databases in the datasets, some of them archival in the sense that they've not been used in years, but I would very much like to retain them.

None of them use triggers; they're pretty basic. Tables with columns, a few indexes each.

I know you can output one DB to SQL and then feed it to the new installation, but that feels very formidable, detail-intensive and time-consuming to me.

Is there a one-shot way to get this done?

Comment: I would give `pg_dump` / `pg_restore` a try before you go looking for alternatives. They do essentially "output one DB to SQL and then feed it to the new installation," but generally aren't "very formidable, detail-intensive and time-consuming".

Comment: Ugh. They are very much so when you have a large number of databases. That process is specifically what I'm interested in avoiding. It's absurdly granular for what I'm trying to accomplish. I may end up going there before this is over if it is the case that there is no actual installation-level migration process, but it seems more than a little surprising that would be so.

Comment: `pg_upgrade` could help if you were on >=8.3. Since you're not, `pg_dumpall`?

Comment: `pg_dump` as a SQL script plus `psql` is not in any way something to rule out. You can actually pipe the output of `pg_dump` to `psql` so no intermediate files are necessary. This can be automated using a shell script. Given the ancient source version I doubt that there is any other way of doing that - you most definitely can not use the existing data directory for anything else than 7.3

Comment: Jay, `pg_dumpall` was *exactly* what I was looking for. All databases migrated successfully, two trivial steps. Awesome. Make it an answer instead of a comment, and I'll vote it up. If not, well, I voted your comment up. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_dump` is the normal answer for a single database, `pg_upgrade` does an entire cluster on the same machine, but only works with >=8.3. Failing all of that, [`pg_dumpall`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pg-dumpall.html) will `pg_dump` all the databases on a server into a single output stream.

Comment: ...at which point, to recreate, you log in as the DB user and do this: `psql -f myBackup.sql template1`